# Slide Show on homepage

Tags: templates

We implemented a slide show in our homepage and would like to place a video as one of the sliding images.

1. Can a slider include a video?
2. If not, can you toggle between video and slider in the CMS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming that your slider is powered by a channel, with a distinct custom field group, you could simply add a new field for your video items.

This could either be a text input field where you would paste the URL to a video (which you then turn into an embedded video using a plugin like [Antenna](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna)), or a [Channel Videos](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-videos) field which will generate the embed code for you, or even a text input field  where you'd paste a simple YouTube video ID, which you'd then include inside some `iframe` embed markup in your template.

This assumes of course that whatever javascript you're using for your slider can accommodate video - but that's outside the scope of this site.